# Error in running web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net web api project in which there is only one api controller and inside that one get method,nothing else.when i try to run it,it is showing below error

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.




    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 300, ServerTimeSpan = 300)]
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Get()
    {
        return repository.GetEmployees().OrderBy(c => c.EmpId);
    }
```

and the url is `http://domain:53538/api/employees`

and WebApiConfig is

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "SearchApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{searchstr}"
         );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApiWithEmpId",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{EmpId}",
               defaults: new { employeeId = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

Comment: put your code and how you are calling that api.

Comment: What is the url you are invoking?

Comment: What is the class name containing the above code? Is it `moviesController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code , i can see that following corresponds to same routing url.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApiWithMovieId",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{movieId}",
           defaults: new { movieId = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

NOTE: In both cases last param is marked as optional, so route is left as `api/{controller}` and when you used `api/movies`, routing system got confused and stopped working!

So you just need to re-arrange routing url, i would suggest replace 1st one ( in my answer to this)

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApiWithMovieId",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{movieId}"

           );
```

So this will make the `movieid` param as mandatory, it will have url `/api/movies/2` , here 2 is movie id

and the later will correspond to `api/movies`( as `id` here is optional - referring to 2nd code block in my answer) , so that your solution will work,

Answer (score 1):

the most likely reason is that you're missing this or something similar in your Global.asax Application_Start

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
{

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));


});
```

This is what tells the application how to map to your Web API Controller.  That said, you may run into a different problem afterwards depending on the structure of your entity.  I've found that Entities with relationships don't serialize well and can often throw a serialization error because it creates a circular reference, so you may need to go into a custom object for the purpose of serialization.  Without a lot more information it's difficult to say for certain what the problem is.  There could also be with the API call or with the structure of the Controller.

The model I use would have you calling

```
$.get('/api/movies/get',,function(result) {});
```

which is why I generally specify the httpmethod and give the api call a meaningful name.

Hopefully this gives enough to figure it out from there.

**EDIT AFTER SEEING UPDATE**

It looks like you have too much in your mapping.  Simplify your mapping and just use your WebAPI on 1 map.  Otherwise it just confuses the routing and doesn't know which map to go to.

In your mapping you have 2 different controller maps that could handle the same request. (the second and third)  They both read the pattern 'api/[^/]+(/[^/]*)?'